# TC7200 UPC modem not shows USB page

Tags: modem, usb-modem

I have TC7200 UPC modem. In manual there is a USB page, but not in my browser. I have connected an external winchester with USB.

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Would you consider adding more information to accurately describe the problem you're having, including operating system and such?

Comment: Not sure to got your problem...you mean that you cannot access the Web Configuration using http://192.168.0.1 (page 20 of the manual) or that you cannot find the USB Web Page Group (page 61 of the manual) ?

Comment: I put the question on stack overflow, with some additional image. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20826148/tc7200-upc-modem-not-shows-usb-page

Comment: My problem that I can not find USB Web Page Group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in the Netherlands, UPC have never implemented the USB-connection in any firmware on their modems (even the Horizon series). So it just doesn't work.

(If they did, they needed to support it and i don't think they wanted to so they left it out)

See a discussion [here](http://www.chelloo.com/upc/index.php?topic=48798.msg640467#msg640467) (in dutch).